# fetching the text from anchor tag

Tags: automated-testing, selenium

```
  <a href="https://www.xyz.com/Vertical-Striped-short-Slve-pant-with-Chest-Pocket-dsdjj.html">Vertical-Striped-short-Slve-pant-with-Chest-Pocket-dsdjj
<br><b>Select Size:</b>&nbsp;S</a>
```

I am trying to fetch the text of anchor tag, but I am getting the text with br tag also.

I am using `getText()` method of selenium API to fetch the text

Please help me to do solve

Note : 
I am expecting to get "Vertical-Striped-short-Slve-pant-with-Chest-Pocket-dsdjj"

Getting text : "Vertical-Striped-short-Slve-pant-with-Chest-Pocket-dsdjj
    Select Size:S"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `getText()` method returns all the text within a HTML element. In this case all the text between the start `<a>` and the end `</a>`. This includes other tags and their contents.

Try to split the string on white spaces and use the first word found.

```
String value = getText();
String[] words = value.split("\\s+");
String result = words[0];
```

Now result should contain the expected string.

Also see this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7899525/how-to-split-a-string-by-space

Comment: Hello @Niels, Thanks for your answer. I found the solution in the same you have provided but actually I want to know is there any way to fetch the text only with in the <a> should not be included text with <b>.Because I am facing this issue regularly in my project.So that I have posted this question.Please let  me know is there any other way for this or not ?. If no then I will mark this answer as CORRECT

Comment: Not that i know of, in your case the <b>old is just part of the link text, but then partial bold. Seems logical to return the full text of the <a>nchor. I would create a wrapper function getWord(element, int) which returns the specified word as a string.

Answer (score 1):

Everything enclosed within the `<a> </a>` tags is considered as part of the link text.

So if you use the `getText()` method of Selenium, you will get the whole text.

If you want a part of the text, you should try to shed the unwanted text.

Get the text and store it in a String variable. Trim the unwanted text from that string and you will have the remaining text as you desire.

This link: "http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_trim.htm" might help you with the trimming of string.

Happy Testing :)

Answer (score -1):

you should use Java String Substring and not string trim,trim removes only trailing and leading spaces

Comment: Komal, perhaps you could add an example?

Comment: Komal, your answer is technically correct, but without an example showing the OP how it works it doesn't add anything to the other answers. As @corsiKa suggests, if you add an example you will improve your answer.